# Css animation when go back to initial style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have scale animation on image, but when the animation finish and go back to the initial size there is no animation, how can i force animation when go back to the initial value?

http://jsbin.com/tijapahuwi/edit?html,css,output

```
@keyframes scaleImg {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

img { 
   transform: scale(0.8);
   animation: scaleImg 1.5s;
   animation-direction: alternate;
}



<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="">
```

Comment: `animation-iteration-count: 2;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`animation-direction: alternate;` is a good start

each iteration runs in alternate direction

so, 2 iterations to get back where you started - i.e.

```
animation-iteration-count: 2;
```

Of course, if you want the total time to be 1.5s, you'll want to change the `1.5s` to `750ms` as well

Answer (score 1):

How is it with?:

```
@keyframes scaleImg {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

img { 
   transform: scale(0.8);
   animation: scaleImg 1.5s;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this solution

```
@keyframes scaleImg {
    0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
}
50% {
    transform: scale(1);
}
100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
}

img { 
   transform: scale(0.8);
   animation: scaleImg 1.5s;
   animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Hope this help you.